# How to add a CSS class to an html element dynamically using only CSS, no JavaScript

Tags: html, css, sass

I work on an older html project, where I have little control on the DOM. I cannot add css classes manually like that:

`<div class="my-class">My Div's Content</div>`

I rather have to specify the selectors in such a manner:

```
body > div:first-of-type > table:nth-of-type(2) > tr:last-of-type > td ....
```

It becomes very long and unreadable, especially if I have to specify html elements located in different levels of nesting.

Would it be possible to add a css class dynamically to the above-specified element in order to use it (the added class), instead of the explicit selector.

In pseudo-code would I imagine something like the following:

```
 body > div:first-of-type > table:nth-of-type(2) 
 > tr:last-of-type > td:add-class('simplified-selector')
```

Comment: You cannot dynamically add classes via CSS.

Comment: I am also not aware of any way of adding classes via CSS. Nevertheless, I have written this question in order to find out if there would be somebody to suggest some hack for doing it anyway.

Comment: Sorry to comment again, just to quickly clarify: this isn't a matter of finding a hack or even opinion. I'm afraid there is literally no way to accomplish what you're asking for in CSS. Good luck out there.

Comment: this is not possible to add a class in HTML element using CSS. you can able to add class using jquery, javascript, PHP.

Answer (score 1):

To add a dynamic class use javascript ou Jquery, you can add CSS with javascript like this, but this is not possible what you want directly in css.

```
<div class="myelement">elem</div>
<script>
let myElem = document.querySelector(".myelement");
document.getElementById(myElem).style.color = "red";
</script>
```

Maybe look the nesting or function with SASS.. : https://la-cascade.io/limbrication-des-selecteur-dans-sass/

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of sass nesting, but find it not so convenient as well. If we could add content with css ::before ::after, then I suppose there might also exist some way to add a class as well, although so far I am on your opinion - that this is impossible.

Comment: I have written that I do not want to use JS. And jQuery is JS.

Comment: if you couldn't add class manually or use Jquery, you don't have any other solution sorry, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a dynamic class to html by css is indeed not possible at all. But ... just as idea to maybe thinking arround (or backwards):

Most often you don't need so many classes to write a clear styling. In most cases only the wrapper element needs a class to build a readable css structure. In some cases a class to the section is enough.

So in your example instead of giving the single elements a class:

```
body > div:first-of-type > table:nth-of-type(2)  > tr:last-of-type > td:add-class('simplified-selector')
```

Just write:

```
body > div:first-of-type > table:nth-of-type(2): add-class('table2')
```

Than do the rest in css direkt:

```
.table2 tr:last-child {
   
   ... your css ...

}
```

That shortens your html work enormous and your css structure keeps readable as well. In the good old time (where the mechanics has been used I believe, - 15 or 20 years old?) the technique to write css had the goal to use as few classes as possible ;-)

The todays 'class overflow' and the ongoing 'div explosion' has come with the great frameworks (so as Bootstrap) ... and some say today as well that that is bad code as styling has nothing to do with the intended semantic of html that should be only reduced to the information which is in it ;-)

Comment: Thanks! You guessed right, I work on such a project where there are very few classes which are specified. I don't even have the .table2 class. In fact the question encompasses exactly that - how to add this ".table2" class. For now I've done it with JS, but if some css work-around popped up, I'd rather us it. The method ":add-class(simplified_selector) " does not exist, actually. I've just introduced it to make it more clear what kind of a method or approach I am looking for.